# HTML submenu won't stay open after mouse out

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a vertical menu with nested sub menus and when clicked the sub menu appears fine. I want the submenu to remain open though even when user move mouse beyond the submenu hover area. So it is a really a paired set of lists.

```
<nav id="menu">
  <ul id ="navigation">
    <li><a id="fly1" href="#" >First menu</a>
      <ul id="dropdown1">
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">tem 2 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">tem 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a id="fly2" href="#" >second menu</a>
      <ul id="dropdown2">
        <li><a href="#"> tem A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item C</a></li>
      </ul></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

And here is the css so far. It works fine but subs menu won't stay open.

```
#menu {
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

#navigation {
  background-color: #0c8fff;
  min-width: 200px;
  float: left;
}

#menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#menu ul li a {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: block;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#menu ul li:hover > ul {
  left: 200px;
}

#menu ul li > ul {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  left: -200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
}

#menu ul li > ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #2e2e2e;
}
```

Comment: It will not stay open because there is only a hover state with css, so when you are over first or second menu with css you have just a hover effect, on mouse enter it will show the menu and on mouse out it will hide it. So you need jQuery or javascript to add a class that will have the same css style as when the menu is opened :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve this results with only html and css. Here it's a possibile solution with JQuery:

Html is the same as yours.

CSS:

```
#menu {
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}


#navigation {
  background-color: #0c8fff;
  min-width: 200px;
  float: left;
}

#menu ul {
  list-style-type:none;
}

#menu ul li a {
  padding:10px 15px;
  display:block;
  color:#333;
  text-decoration:none;
}

#menu ul li > ul {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  top: 0;
  /*z-index: -1;
  left: -200px; */
  min-width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  left: 200px;
  display: none;
}

#menu ul li > ul li a:hover {
  background-color:#2e2e2e;
}
```

Javascript:

```
(function() {
  $('[id^=fly]').click( function() {
    $(this).siblings().toggle();
  });
})();
```

Here is a link to the working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qbukx26j/

Keep in mind that you may want to add some more logic since my solution doesn't keep track if both the submenus are open and it's buggy if you open one submenus before closing the other one.

EDIT
The submenu is displayed only up to a certain point because the #menu has the overflow set too auto: it means that some browsers will display a scrollbar if the content is bigger than the container. If you remove it, it just works. Here is the new JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1s2zm2b0/

Comment: Looks promising - can't get it to work yet though. The sub menu isn't showing. Will try again.

Comment: Ok I stripped out my main div that contained everything and it now works. I see it works once and then again and then goes blank. Not sure how to prevent that and keep it fluid (java skills not best - this is for a Help book for an OBJc project.)but will tinker a bit more.

Comment: What may be complicating things is I already have a javascript:

Comment: Well, you can try to see if the page gives you some errors: for example on Google Chrome push the F12 key to open the element inspector and in the console tab check if there are any errors. Other browsers have similar functions too.

Answer (score 0):

Ok So I changed the html a bit and the js (with some jquery examples)

```
<nav id="menu">
        <ul id ="navigation">
            <li class="fly"><a  href="#" >First menu</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 2 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="fly"><a  href="#" >second menu</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="#">item A</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item B</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item C</a></li>
                </ul></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

and js...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fly .submenu").hide(); 

    $(".fly a").click(function(){
        $(".fly .submenu").hide(); 
        $(this).parent().find("ul").toggle(); 
    });
});
```

Now it toggles back and forth and menus stay open. This works as I want it.

see fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/rdutoit/em6LxdLc/  but now there is a new problem. The submenu is displayed but only up to a certain length which is maybe 1 item more than the main list length. Any ideas? Thanks,  Rob

Comment: Hello there! I added a possible solution: you can find it at the end of my answer.